# this code may be enough to properly insert a banner?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, ads, banner

this is my activity and XML
I wanted to know if such an application loaded on play store can function. 
because I am inspired by this guide https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals?csw=1#play I saw that it says a lot more code. 
what do you think I should add more or can also be operated so the banner?

by chance could you tell me how to insert a banner in a listview?

what are exactly these onResume, onPause, OnDestroy with the banner?

ACTIVITY A

```
public class StagioniActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

AdView adView;
ImageButton Gruppi;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //creazione fullscreen activity
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.stagioni_activity);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); 
    }

    // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

//configurazione bottone Stagioni
        Gruppi = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        Gruppi.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.imageButton1:
        //azioni da fare
        //definisco l'intenzione da fare con il pulsante
        Intent gruppi = new Intent(StagioniActivity.this,GruppiPuntateActivity.class);
        //faccio aprire l'activity desiderata
        startActivity(gruppi);
        break;
    }
}



}
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/homecaceracafe1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottonehome"
        android:text="In arrivo altre stagioni" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1009048320436078/2128669942" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To show Ads in your application all you have to do is declare it in your XML. Simple as that, you don't have to call it through code to show it, unless you want to show an Interstial Ad.

Just make sure your `adUnitId` is correct.

Comment: adUnitID are those that begin with CA-app -pub xxxxxxxxxxxxx / xxxxxxxxx right? 
the publisher ID should not be included?

Comment: You have to include everything:

ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx

If you don't it won't work.